# Dependency errors for any apt command

Tags: 18.04, apt, cuda

When attempting to install or remove packages I am running into an error something to do with cuda.

For example, installing curl (which I already have installed):

```
sudo apt install curl
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version (7.58.0-2ubuntu3.16).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-libraries-dev-10-2 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.2.89) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-samples-10-2 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.2.89) but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-visual-tools-10-2 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.2.89) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When doing this with a package that is not already installed it also gives those same missing dependencies (`libcublas-dev`) and fails to install.

Any help?

Edit: Trying `sudo apt --fix-broken install` gives a similar error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcublas-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcublas-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 613 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/42.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 114 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y 
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.40  libcublas-dev 10.2.2.89-1 [42.3 MB]
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'cuda-libraries-10-2' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 466055 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libcublas-dev_10.2.2.89-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcublas-dev (10.2.2.89-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cuda-repo-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.40/./libcublas-dev_10.2.2.89-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/cublas_v2.h', which is also in package nvidia-cuda-dev:amd64 10.0.130-0lambda3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cuda-repo-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.40/./libcublas-dev_10.2.2.89-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try doing `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install curl` and see if that works properly.

Comment: @cocomac Still getting the same error as shown above.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you made any changes to your /etc/apt/sources.list?

Comment: Looks like you tried to install Cuda more than one way, and did not clean up between the attempts. So you have conflicting packages floating around that sort-of work and soft-of don't.  If that is indeed what happened, go back and clean up. Keep track of exactly what you install, when, and why -- that makes cleaning up much easier.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks for the insight - this machine was used by multiple people that seems likely. How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the key error line:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cuda-repo-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.40/./libcublas-dev_10.2.2.89-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/cublas_v2.h', which is also in package nvidia-cuda-dev:amd64 10.0.130-0lambda3
```

Let's break that down a little bit:

```
dpkg: error processing PACKAGE A:
 trying to overwrite FILE, which is also in PACKAGE B

PACKAGE A = libcublas-dev:amd64 10.2.2.89-1
PACKAGE B = nvidia-cuda-dev:amd64 10.0.130-0lambda3
FILE      = /usr/include/cublas_v2.h
```

The first problem: Package A and Package B are trying to provide the same file. That means that the packages *conflict*. That conflict is what's causing the error.

The second problem: Look at the version numbers of each package...they don't match. They probably should.

- You --the human admin-- must decide which version is appropriate for your system.

Take a look at `apt cache policy` for both of those packages. If the packages come from *different* sources, that's probably bad.

- If you have multiple sources, you --the human admin-- must decide which source provides the appropriate packages for your system.

To fix the problem, you must make two decisions (in the bullets above). Then you must implement your decisions:

1. Disable or delete the conflicting or unwanted sources. They are not helping you anyway.
2. Uninstall conflicting or wrong-version packages.

It's also possible to use the quick-and-dirty `--force-overwrite` flag with apt so the error message goes away. However, I don't recommend that...it doesn't actually solve the underlying problem of mixed sources providing wrong-version packages, which might someday break Cuda entirely.